# Compressing Excel file does not reduce the size

Tags: python, automation, directory, path, zip

I am using python to automate the conversion of Excel file to zip folder. The file is converted to zip using below code.

```
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile

path = r'C:/Users/kj/Desktop/Results'
os.chdir(path)
new_path = "C:/Users/kj/Desktop/New folder/"
ZipFile(new_path+"Week6.zip", 'w').write("Week6.csv")
```

The problem is below code is converting it to zip file but not reducing the size of the file. It remains same. But when I manually zip file, it reduces the size considerably. Please suggest what can be done to do it manually?

Comment: Are you talking about excel or csv? There's a big difference, because `.xlsx` file is already a zip.

Answer (score 1):

Because the default compression algorithm is `ZIP_STORED` which basically saves exact files in uncompressed format. so you have to mention your compression algorithm like `lzma`:

```
ZipFile(new_path+"Week6.zip", mode='w', compression=ZIP_LZMA)
```

Comment: For `compression=` I would recommend using `ZIP_DEFLATED` because all the others are non-standard and other tools may have problems reading the files.

Comment: @martineau valuable point , thanks